# Indirect objects in a "faire + infinitive" context and elsewhere

Tags: syntaxe, constructions-causatives

The question is on the two instances of *lui* as found in this excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus, in which Meursault, the narrator, refers to himself as *me* and his lawyer as *le*.

> Il a réfléchi. Il m’a demandé s’il pouvait dire que ce jour-là j’avais dominé mes sentiments naturels. Je lui ai dit : « Non, parce que c’est faux. » Il m’a regardé d’une façon bizarre, comme si je lui inspirais un peu de dégoût. Il m’a dit presque méchamment que dans tous les cas le directeur et le personnel de l’asile seraient entendus comme témoins et que « cela pouvait me jouer un très sale tour ». Je **lui** ai fait remarquer que cette histoire n’avait pas de rapport avec mon affaire, mais il m’a répondu seulement qu’il était visible que je n’avais jamais eu de rapports avec la justice.
>        Il est parti avec un air fâché. J’aurais voulu le retenir, lui expliquer que je désirais sa sympathie, non pour être mieux défendu, mais, si je puis dire, naturellement. Surtout, je voyais que je le mettais mal à l’aise. Il ne me comprenait pas et il m’en voulait un peu. J’avais le désir de **lui** affirmer que j’étais comme tout le monde, absolument comme tout le monde. Mais tout cela, au fond, n’avait pas grande utilité et j’y ai renoncé par paresse.

My reading of the two instances (confirmed by English translations) is as follows.

- The first *lui* supplies the agent of *remarquer*.  So it is the lawyer who is to note something.
- The second *lui* does not supply the agent of any verb. It is a dative complement of *affirmer*, i.e. the audience to whom the affirmation is made.

**Question**

1. When grammarians parse a sentence like *Je lui ai fait remarquer que* do they say that *lui* is governed by *fait* or *remarquer*? To say that *fait* governs *lui* may amount to understanding the sentence as saying, "I caused *to him* : the remarking of."  To say that *remarquer* governs *lui* may amount to understanding the sentence as saying, "I caused : the remarking *on his part* of." (I am not suggesting that these two readings would paint two distinct situations. I am only asking about the grammatical treatment the type of sentence may have received.)
2. Would it be a sound principle if I understood that an indirect object (such as *lui*) can supply an agent for an infinitive ONLY when that infinitive is within a faire + infinitive or similar context?
3. This question is actually on the scope of "within a faire + infinitive or similar context." Namely, is there any chance of *avoir le désir de* creating a "context similar to faire + infinitive" so that we have to (or may) say that *lui* is the agent of *affirmer*, i.e. that Meursault wanted the laywer to make (vs. hear) the affirmation? (I don't necessarily mean in the Camus passage above.  But the question is whether, in any context, *avoir le désir de lui + infinitive* could ever be ambiguous between *lui* being the agent vs. the dative complement of the infinitive. (I believe in some other languages what is known as "dative of agent" does not require a modal or semi-modal like *faire* but may also occur with e.g. a passive participial.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Je lui fait remarquer que = Je *montre à lui* que .

Construction is:

- faire + verbe de perception + COD + COI (or +COI + COD)
- pronoun COI + verbe de **perception** + COD

***remarquer* is shared between *je* and *lui***

*lui* is COI of *fais/fais remarquer*, as in *je lui donne une pomme*.

*lui* is also (co-)subject of *remarquer*.

> Je fais remarquer à cette personne que ...

as in

> Je lui fais voir ...
>
> Je lui fais observer ...
>
> Je luis fais croire ...
>
> Je luis fais entendre ...

**Question 2: yes, but it is in general case with COD, not COI:**

COI only works as in question 1 with verbs of perception (co-perception).

In general case, it is a COD, with several semi-auxiliary verbs (faire, laisser, and verbs of perception: entendre, voir, ...)

Then you could also have:  pronoun COD + faire + construction infinitif.

but faire + COD + construction infinitif doesnt exist.

> Je le fais remarquer cet objet.
>
> Je le fais voir cet objet.
>
> Je le fais monter ...

**Question 3: It is different. subject of *avoir le désir* is *je*.**

J'avais le désir de lui affirmer = ... d'affirmer à lui . lui is **just** COI

Comment: Thanks. But my question 2 is about *lui* (not about *le*) serving e.g. as COI for *fais* and agent for *remarquer* in *Je lui ai fait remarquer que*, as you yourself have confirmed.

Comment: @Catomic - I adjusted my answer. Yes, but only for verbs of perception. In general, it is COD, and the other person is the only subject of the action.